# WebImage class missing on MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been developing a MVC 4 web app but I couldn't find where is the reference to WebImage. I also added a reference to "System.Web.Helpers". I'm inside a Controller and there is no shortcut or even helps/tips to find this class.

```
public ActionResult Images()
{
    WebImage w
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding `using System.Web.Helper;` after adding reference to System.Web.Helpers (in System.Web.Helpers.dll) you can use `WebImage` class

Or try with

```
public ActionResult Images()
{
    System.Web.Helpers.WebImage w =new System.Web.Helpers.WebImage("~/images/Desert.jpg");
}
```

As Per your comment with the below image [image]

Classes like AntiFogery came from  [`System.Web.WebPages (in System.Web.WebPages.dll)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) I think you are added wrong reference. you need to add `System.Web.Helpers (in System.Web.Helpers.dll)`

When you add reference you can check the dll details by moving mouse pointer over the assembly name like below

[image]

Comment: take a look at [link](http://gandarez.com.br/System.Web.Helpers.WebImage.jpg). Can't see WebImage class

Comment: I didn't find this dll. Take a look at this [link](http://gandarez.com.br/helpe.png). I had to add it by browsing files.